# Is it better to compute log(x/(y*z)) or log(x)-log(y)-log(z)?

Tags: numbers, numerical-methods, logarithm

Mathematically, `log(x/(y*z))` and `log(x)-log(y)-log(z)` [are equivalent](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28x+%2F+%28y+*+z%29%29+%3D+log%28x%29+-+log%28y%29+-+log%28z%29). On a computer, they will give different answers. Which is preferable to compute?

Comment: I tried with a small variety of numbers in VB.NET using the Double type and got the same answer to 15 S.F. both ways. What language are you using to get different results, and what are the magnitudes of the numbers you are using?

Comment: "better" is subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Log` is numerical stable but division not so. Imagine `y` and `z` are very close to `0`. Then `y * z` has a great probability to be evaluated to `0` and `x / (y * z)` to overflow. But `log(y)` even for very small `y` gives accurate results. So `log(x)-log(y)-log(z)` is expected to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The former would be faster, the latter more precise so it depends on what you need.